# How to find out where the "grub" is installed

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade, grub2

My Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS is asking me during "apt-get dist-upgrade" where to install "GRUB" update.How can I simply find out which partition/disc is the proper answer? How to find out where GRUB is currently installed? I found similar question and answer but how to do it without installing additional script? I will be grateful for your advice.

Similar question: [How to know the partition where grub is installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30341/how-to-know-the-partition-where-grub-is-installed)

Cheers :)

Comment: How is your question different from the one you gave on the link?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### Disclaimer

**`dd` command is extremely dangerous . Should be used with caution . Use it at your own risk. Below command uses `dd`, is tested by me, and will not harm your system. Do not change the format of the command , the only thing you can change are the letters of the device**

**eg: /dev/sda , /dev/sdb, /dev/sdc ...etc**

---

You can examine the first 512 bytes of the device with `dd` command through `strings`

For /dev/sda

`sudo dd bs=512 count=1 if=/dev/sda 2>/dev/null | strings`

The results in my device

```
ZRr=
`|f 
\|f1
GRUB
Geom
Hard Disk
Read
 Error
```

as you can see , GRUB is there.

[source](https://serverfault.com/questions/61400/how-do-i-tell-if-grub-is-installed-on-a-device)

Comment: Fdisk displayed inf. So where should GRUB upgrade go on Windows Azure - dev/sda or dev/sda1 ?

Comment: Grub can be installed anywhere but from default installed only in the MBR of the device. /dev/sda1 is not a device is a partition. It is not recommended for the bootloader to be installed in a partition. You should always check the letters of the device /dev/sda or /dev/sdb , not /sda1 or sdb1.

Comment: it either outputs either `/\`8:` or nothing in my PC, even after I run `grub-install`

Answer (score 3):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing try this documentation from official source

Answer (score 2):

During installation, you will be offered to choose the "Device for bootloader installation". Please select: * either the disk (eg /dev/sdX, not /dev/sdXY) on which the BIOS is setup to boot (recommended for normal use) * OR the partition (eg /dev/sdXY, not /dev/sdX) on which Ubuntu (/boot, else /) will be installed (only if you want to chainload it from another bootloader; if any doubt, do NOT choose this)

REFERENCE : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing