# How does the system know where to reinstall grub?

Tags: grub2

When GRUB is upgraded, or a `do-release-upgrade` is performed, how does Ubuntu know where to reinstall GRUB?  GRUB could be in the MBR or at the beginning of a partition, but I can't find where this information is written on a running system.

Answer (score 0):

Grub always installed at the MBR of the disk where Ubuntu is installed. `do-release-upgrade` is capable to read this information (where Ubuntu is installed) and it will install grub there. No matter if you have 2 or 3 HDDs the upgrader reads the one where Ubuntu is installed. i.e. I have two disks /dev/sda = Windows and /dev/sdb = Ubuntu. Grub will be installed (or re-installed) in /dev/sdb and not /dev/sda.

Additionally, if you want to see where grub is installed see this [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/205311/95393).