# how to remove ubuntu from dual ubuntu boot with Windows 10 as third OS

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

At the moment i have 3 OS installed in my system. i.e. Windows 10 on my SSD , Ubuntu 16.04 on my HDD along side Ubuntu 18.04 . Now I will like to remove Ubuntu 18.04 from my system and keep win10 and Ubuntu 16.
I want to properly remove Ubuntu 18 from Ubuntu 16 without effecting my current setup of dual boot.

Comment: Where is grub installed?

Comment: I have no idea where grub is installed

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/30347/27968 and update your question.